# Entity framework foreign key instances

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.3

I have a table with two foreign key fields point to colour table.

> BookCover -> ForegroundColour and
>
> BookCover -> BackgroundColour

When I do Reverse Engineer Code First, it generates `Colour` and `Colour1` in the `BookCover` class.

```
public virtual Colour Colour { get; set; }
public virtual Colour Colour1 { get; set; }
```

I have set the foreign name to be `ForegroundColour` and `BackgroundColour`.
Is there a easy way let Entity frame work generate the `ForegroundColour` and `BackgroundColour` instead of `Colou`r and `Colour1`?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the association names in the EF model designer. Once they have been changed, the framework will remember the new names, even if you update the model at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue but I believe the answer to the question is you simply have to rename the Navagation property to what you want. The Entity Framwork designer will always keep you changes to the property names on the Conceptual side of things.